# No entiendo porque creo que ya uso este tipo de consultas y esta me da error

Tags: php

Consulta me genera este error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\mi sistema\mi sistema\consultas.php on line
>   90
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\mi sistema\mi
>   sistema\consultas.php on line 91

Mi codigo

```
$query=$db->query("SELECT * FROM accidente");
$result = mysqli_query($query, $db);
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La Línea  `$query=$db->query("SELECT * FROM accidente")` básicamente lo que está haciendo es ejecutar la  consulta pasada por parámetro y el valor devuelto será un `mysqli_result` *(si se ejecuta correctamente)* luego le asigna a su variable `$query` *(en caso que exista algún error retornará false)*

En la línea `$result = mysqli_query($query, $db)` ejecutas la consulta en teoría nuevamente , pero hay un error y es que el orden de los parámetros son `mysqli_query($db,$query)` **pero** no tu variable ya que si se ejecuto con éxito lo primero tendrás un `mysqli_result`, en caso de errores un valor `FALSE` y no una consulta en sí.

Para solucionar esto en primer lugar debe elegir una opción para realizar la `query` si elige la primera su código sería

```
$query=$db->query("SELECT * FROM accidente");
while ($rows = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   print_r($rows);
}
```

Si elige la segunda forma sería.

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,"select * from accidente");
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   print_r($rows);
}
```

> Como nota adicional sugiero emplear sentencias preparadas con
>   extensión [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) y no estaría de más leer [¿Cómo evitar la
>   Inyección SQL ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: tututututu nada chico yo uso mysql asi porque yo soy es malandro chico, .... xd gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo creo que tu problema es que esta al revez en esta linea

```
$result = mysqli_query($query, $db);
```

Si miras la documentación de PHP veras lo siguiente:

```
mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

espero te sea de ayuda la respuesta para la solucion seria esta:

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

Comment: ahora arroja este error Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\mi sistema\mi sistema\consultas.php on line 90

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\mi sistema\mi sistema\consultas.php on line 91